# Google Lighthouse NGINX performance issues

Tags: nginx, lighthouse

I was wanting to see if anyone could assist me with a Google lighthouse issue on my website made using NGINX. As I'm creating a web app, I'm using google lighthouse to monitor my progress as I go along. My performance score ends up being 0 every time.

Everything else ends ups coming out with good scores, but I might be missing a lot more. I suspect I'm missing a lot of lines of code to add or something like that but honestly I just want to be pointed in the right direction?

Screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNABz.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLhYM.jpg

Comment: do you want to share the URL in the comments so we can have a look, at the moment there is no information that is useful.

Comment: I added the Imgur images. I would need to know what to present. As it stands I did not change much of the nginx settings and kept all of them at default. I'm just a little confused as to why my site is has performance score of 0 :/

Comment: It doesn't have a score of zero, it has a score of "oh crap there was a major error when trying to run a performance trace" . Unfortunately screen shots will not be useful and there could be thousands of causes which is why I suggested a URL to test against. One thing to check for is that you haven't got any debug (`debugger`) statements in your JS. Open Developer Tools and reload the site - if it pauses then that is your problem. Other than that console errors are worth exploring and at that point we really need a URL to test against as options are varied.